# Django: filtering queryset by "parameter has part of field's value"?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a simple model:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

and it has some representative names like `Starbucks`, `McDonald's`, etc. as shown below.

```
 id |   name   
----+----------
  1 | Starbucks
  2 | McDonald's
  3 | ...
```

And I also have some place names as query parameter, for example:

- Starbucks Pike Place
- McDonald's Sand Lake Road
- Another Starbucks Out There

What I'm trying to achieve is to filter/get appropriate `Place` object with given parameters, determine whether it has part of place's `name`.

How can I do this with django's QuerySet API?
Have checked references and forum to find something like below but was no luck:

```
Place.objects.get(name__ispartof=PARAM)
# or
Place.objects.get(PARAM__contains=Q('name'))
```

In Postgres, my case may equivalent to:

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE 'Starbucks Pike Place' LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
```

Should I have to perform a `raw()` SQL query for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found a horrible way to do it in the ORM without needing raw SQL.  Hopefully someone else will be able to find something better.

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, CharField, Value, F

param = 'Starbucks Pike Place'
myparam = ExpressionWrapper(Value(param), output_field=CharField())
Place.objects.annotate(param=myparam).filter(param__contains=F('username'))
```

Comment: In my case, `Place` model stores only representative names, and detailed names are given by parameter. So I can't use regex here.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question.  Can you give a better example, like specifying:  1) exactly what rows are in the table, 2) what the query string is, and 3) which rows should be returned for that query.

Comment: I have added example rows to the post.
Detailed case specification:
1) The model has an object whose `name` is 'Starbucks'.
2) And query string, 'Starbucks Pike Place'.
3) I want to get the 'Starbucks' object, due to its `name` being part of given query string.

Comment: And if there was a place with the name "Pike" you would want that returned, too?  So it's if the query string "overlaps" the name?

Comment: Yes, exactly :) Thanks for clarifying my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Place.objects.get(name__contains=PARAM)` should do it. Note that you can also use `icontains` instead of `contains` if you'd like the query to be case-insensitive.

Comment: `name__contains` is equivalent to `SELECT ... WHERE name LIKE {{param}}` (pseudocode), my case it's `SELECT ... WHERE {{param}} LIKE name` as I wrote in the original post.

Comment: it's not `name__contains` but more like `name__contained_by`.